# Type function may not be injective

Tags: haskell

I am attempting to prove some axioms about odd and even natural numbers. I am using three defined data types in my proof.

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat

data Even (a :: Nat) :: * where
  ZeroEven :: Even Z
  NextEven :: Even n -> Even (S (S n))

data Odd (a :: Nat) :: * where
  OneOdd :: Odd (S Z)
  NextOdd :: Odd n -> Odd (S (S n))
```

I also have the following type families defined for addition and multiplication.

```
type family   Add (n :: Nat) (m :: Nat) :: Nat
type instance Add Z m = m
type instance Add (S n) m = S (Add n m)

type family   Mult (n :: Nat) (m :: Nat) :: Nat
type instance Mult Z m = Z
type instance Mult (S n) m = Add (Mult n m) n
```

I have functions defined for proving that the sum of two evens is even and that the product of two evens is even.

```
evenPlusEven :: Even n -> Even m -> Even (Add n m)
evenPlusEven ZeroEven m = m
evenPlusEven (NextEven n) m = NextEven (evenPlusEven n m)

evenTimesEven :: Even n -> Even m -> Even (Mult n m)
evenTimesEven ZeroEven m = ZeroEven
evenTimesEven (NextEven n) m = evenPlusEven (EvenTimesEven n m) n
```

I am using the `GADTs`, `DataKinds`, `TypeFamilies`, and `UndecidableInstances` language extension and GHC version 7.10.3. Running `evenPlusEven` gives me the results I expect, but I get an compilation error when I include `evenTimesEven`. The error is:

```
Could not deduce (Add (Add (Mult n1 m) n1) ('S n1)
                  ~ Add (Mult n1 m) n1)
from the context (n ~ 'S ('S n1))
  bound by a pattern with constructor
             NextEven :: forall (n :: Nat). Even n -> Even ('S ('S n)),
           in an equation for `evenTimesEven'
  at OddsAndEvens.hs:71:16-25
NB: `Add' is a type function, and may not be injective
Expected type: Even (Mult n m)
  Actual type: Even (Add (Mult n1 m) n1)
Relevant bindings include
  m :: Even m
    (bound at OddsAndEvens.hs:71:28)
  n :: Even n1
    (bound at OddsAndEvens.hs:71:25)
  evenTimesEven :: Even n -> Even m -> Even (Mult n m)
    (bound at OddsAndEvens.hs:70:1)
In the expression: evenPlusEven (evenTimesEven n m) n
In an equation for `evenTimesEven':
    evenTimesEven (NextEven n) m = evenPlusEven (evenTimesEven n m) n
```

The type family instances for `Mult` compile fine and if I replace the last line of `evenTimesEven` with an error throw I can compile the code and the function runs fine with an input of `ZeroEven` which makes me think that my instance for `Mult` is correct and my implementation of `evenTimesEven` is the problem, but I'm unsure of why.

Shouldn't `Even (Mult n m)` and `Even (Add (Mult n1 m) n1)` have the same kind?

Comment: Shouldn't `evenPlusEven ZeroEven m = n` be `evenPlusEven ZeroEven m = m`?

Comment: Writing `*` for `evenTimesEven`, `+` for `evenPlusEven`, and `2+` for `NextEven`, you have written `(2+n)*m = n*m + n`; it should be `(2+n)*m = n*m + m + m` or similar instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below, I'll abuse common mathematical notation.

```
from the context (n ~ 'S ('S n1))
```

From this, we get that `n = 2+n1`.

```
Expected type: Even (Mult n m)
```

We need to prove `n*m` even, i.e. `(2+n1)*m` even.

```
Actual type: Even (Add (Mult n1 m) n1)
```

We have proved `(n1*m)+n1` even. This is not the same. The additional term should be `m`, not `n1`, and it should be added twice.

Comment: I can't get `evenPlusEven (evenTimesEven n m) (evenPlusEven m m)` to compile. Is that the solution you had in mind? [Here's my code](https://ideone.com/R4gsc6).

Comment: @4castle Associativity matters. That would make `(n*m)+(m+m)` but I guess you need `(((n*m)+m)+m)`. I don't have a solution in mind, but I would not be surprised if in such exercises some commutativity or associativity issues arise.

Comment: I found a typo where `Add (Mult n m) n` is supposed to be `Add (Mult n m) m`, and then I applied your fix, and now it's working!